# question about sidebar display when using node group

Tags: geometry-nodes

actually I want to change the name of these dots in a node group, for example I wanna change the name of multiplier dot and addend dot into other name or else.
[image]
However, my sidebar does not have "group"or"option" display, all it has are item view and tool. is there anyone could help me to show group on sidebar? thank you! Mine have no group sidebar, but other people have that on sidebar as these pics...
[image]

[image]

Comment: Welcome! What you're looking for is the side panel *of the GN editor*. You had looked at *the 3D viewport's* side panel. That's another side panel. Move the mouse into the GN editor and press then the N key to open its side panel. I think on the 2nd screenshot they placed a GN editor into the right area of the screen and expanded the panel that now covers completely the GN editor area.

Comment: @Blunder That is a complete (and probably correct) answer. Please post it as such instead of as a comment.

Comment: thank you and happy new year!